# Positioning issues

Tags: html, css, position

I'm working on this template design for one of my personal projects, I keep running into issues as I'm new to html and css. To make things easier to understand and explain I've taken a screenshot and temporary changed background colors for the divs to different colors that way it's easier to see where its at on the pages.

Please see screenshot below:
[image]

I'm trying to place that dark colored box inside the blue area next to the red box. Now, that I'm thinking about it. Some of these divs might not even be necessary. Do I really need that blue div on top of the lightblue background ?

The dark colored box doesn't want to float right next to the red box for some reason.. It keeps going under the other elements.

This is my html

```
<div class="three-reasons">
        <div class="reason-one">
            <div class="news-container">
                <h2>Recent News</h2>
                <h3>TechTarget<span> August 13, 2015</span></h3>
                <p>Adios, Legacy network architectures: Making the jump to NSX</p>
                <h3>Dallas Business Journal<span> August 13, 2015</span></h3>
                <p>What Nexis is doing on the Hill to influence future cyber security legislation</p>
                <div class="side-div"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="client-showcase">
        <h1>Client Showcase</h1>
        <img src="images/our-clients.png" class="client-logos" alt="Our Clients" />
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 - 2016 Nexishost, inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my css

```
.three-reasons {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.news-container {
    width: 220px;
    background-color: red;
}

.side-div {
    width: 220px;
    height: 138px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #474747;
}

.reason-one {
    width: 470px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.reason-one h2 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.reason-one h3 {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.reason-one span {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.reason-one p {
    color: #333;
    max-width: 220px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the full width div at the top of your page is closing before the grey element. Here is the code from your question extracted and aligned correctly:

```
<div class="three-reasons">
    <div class="reason-one">
        <div class="news-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="client-showcase">
</div>
```

I've also removed the content to make this even clearer (note, aligning your HTML carefully will save you pain).

As the `.client-showcase` div is completely outside the `.three-reasons` div it will never appear within it. This is the reason that it is appearing underneath and won't float next to the red box.

I've built you a little structure here that [achieves what you want](https://jsfiddle.net/pyp70Lcz/14/) - you're right, a lot of the divs aren't necessary.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='box-1'>
    </div>
    <div class='box-2'>
    </div>    
</div>
```

The container is the light blue box, it's 980px wide. Inside it are two boxes. These boxes are both 220px wide and 200px high and they have `display: inline-block` set to make them line up beside each other. You can put

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.box-1, 
.box-2 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can put content inside them now and remove the hard-coded heights, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pyp70Lcz/17/) - note how the height controls the height of the container and that `vertical-align: top;` has been added to make them line up with the top of the container.

Comment: That is awesome, thank you so much. Your code is so much cleaner than mine. I knew something looked funny when looking over my code and seeing all these divs one inside another.. You went through the trouble of studying, fixing and explaining this issue. Thanks for taking the time to do that. I will erase what I have for this issue and follow your suggestions. Hopefully the end result will be as good looking as yours. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: thanks :-) I think when starting out it's easy to end up with a bit more in the code than necessary and this often leads to problems, I find that if I start to remove stuff bit by bit and see the effect I can get rid of a lot and sometimes the problem shows itself :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this piece of code. it is not efficient but working

```
.side-div {
    width: 220px;
    height: 138px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #474747;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `news-container` `div` have only 220px `width`. Increase the width to 470px.

For floating the `side-div` to right, place it above the other contents -

```
<div class="news-container">
    <div class="side-div"></div>
    <h2>Recent News</h2>
    <h3>TechTarget<span> August 13, 2015</span></h3>
    <p>Adios, Legacy network architectures: Making the jump to NSX</p>
    <h3>Dallas Business Journal<span> August 13, 2015</span></h3>
    <p>What Nexis is doing on the Hill to influence future cyber security legislation</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fn7kxckk/